# is it possible to add event listeners to svg paths in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

i'm working on a quran application where i'll be displaying quran pages as SVGs, the SVGs consist of paths for each verse in the page, i want to be able to add events to those paths for example when they are clicked i want to highlight the verse (path basically) or show a pop up menu and such. how can this be possible with react native?

in my app i'm using react native svg and react native svg transformer so import the SVGs as components to display them.

[example SVG file](https://jsfiddle.net/18baretm/)

an example of this functionality i think [Quran Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quran.labs.androidquran&hl=en&gl=US) does something similar as they are doing exactly what i'm trying to do

Comment: In your jsfiddle svg all verses actually merged in one single compound path (the last `<path>`). For highlighting verses individually, you need to split this compound path into separate `<path>`  elements (for each verse).  You can use a graphic editor like Adobe Illustrator, inkscape etc for this task. Admittedly quite a lot of work. An easier approach could be to add rectangles that will become the pointer area. See this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/bGmVeeO)

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-svg](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg) supports events on the svg elements, the [touch events](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md#touch-events) supported in react-native-svg are:

- disabled
- onPress
- onPressIn
- onPressOut
- onLongPress
- delayPressIn
- delayPressOut
- delayLongPress

You can use these events to provide interactivity to your react-native-svg components.

```html
<Circle
  cx="50%"
  cy="50%"
  r="38%"
  fill="red"
  onPress={() => alert('Press on Circle')}
/>
```

Just make sure to convert your svgs into react-native-svg using [this tool](https://react-svgr.com/playground/). It should be doable.

Comment: is there a way to do this with react native svg transformer? instead of having to convert all 604 SVGs to react native components myself, maybe i can directly add the event listener through the transformer library?

Comment: I don't think so. The way I see it is, by converting those svgs you would have more control over the whole behaviour, since your Quran app will depend heavily on those svgs and the control that has to be done around them.